# How to sum numbers within text in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im looking to sum the numbers within a cell of text, into another cell.

[Example of Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aug3d.png)

Comment: What is it you tried? Also, please remove the Excel tags if you are working with GS.

Comment: Use left() mid() right() len() and find() but is GS same as excel?

Comment: use regexextract and sum

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=sum(split(join("|",REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([0-9]+)","($1)"))),"|"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear Col C entirely (including the header "TOTAL"). Then place the following formula in cell C1:

`=ArrayFormula({"TOTAL"; MMULT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"[^\d]+","~")&REPT("~0",25),"~"),COUNTA(A2:A),25),SEQUENCE(25,1,1,0))})`

You can change the header text within the formula itself if you like.

This one formula will produce the header and all results for all rows in Col C.

**How It Works**

`REGEXREPLACE` replaces any groupings of anything other than digits with a single tilde (~). To this new string, `REPT` adds a repeated string of 25 instances of `~0`.

`SPLIT` then splits this at every tilde, which sends each number (and zero appended by `REPT` into its own column. Some rows at this point will have more columns than others, because you have a different numbers of listed items in each of your A2:A cells.

`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` constrains the results into a regular grid with as many rows as there are non-null entries in A2:A and 25 columns. Based on your data samples, this should be more columns than you'd ever have listed items per cell in A2:A. Those `REPT` zeros will fill in all columns after your last actual value in A2:A.

`MMULT` can now act on the constrained grid, along with `SEQUENCE` to do row-by-row addition.