# How do I find the AVERAGE from the SUM of any occurrences of numbers in a text string?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average

The solution to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70241060/how-to-sum-numbers-within-text-in-google-sheets) works perfectly for summing all numbers within a text string! Is there a way to use this formula, but pull an AVERAGE from all numbers in the cell? So, instead of the output of a cell containing the numbers 5, 3, and 8 being 16, I'd like to be able to get the average of these 3 numbers instead. (5,3,8 outputs 5 as a whole number with no decimals). Here's the original formula posted in the link above:

```
=ArrayFormula({"TOTAL"; MMULT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"[^\d]+","~")&REPT("~0",25),"~"),COUNTA(A2:A),25),SEQUENCE(25,1,1,0))})
```

I tried changing the COUNTA function to AVERAGE, but it broke the formula as it needed to divide by zero.

The end solution I'm looking for would be to take the output of this formula and divid it by the count of number occurrences in the cell. But, I'm not sure how or what to modify to test the number of occurrences? Thanks!

Comment: What language used?

Comment: why not use the other answer and replace `sum(` with `average(`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=index(map(regexreplace(A2:A&"","[^\d\.]"," "),lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,round(average(--regexextract(Σ,regexreplace(Σ,"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)","($1)"))))))))
```

- *the formula also looks out for*  `decimal numbers (if any)`, `presence of any characters that needs to be escaped for regex`, `solo numericals`

[image]